Put commentary about input on same line and to the right of the input area
Consider this HTML5 Form.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Centering on Vertical Line</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>

<style>
textarea {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  resize: none;
}

.formInputs {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.formInputs label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.formInputs input,
.formInputs textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
<!-- Desired output is <span> contents to be on same line as the form.
-->
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="sectionA">

  <p class="formInputs">
    <label for="polNum">Policy Number:</label>
    <input id="polNum" name="polNum" type="text" /><span>Your policy number begins with the letter K</span>
  </p>

  <p class="formInputs">
    <label for="membNbr">Control Number:</label>
    <input id="membNbr" name="membNbr" type="text" /><
  </p>

  <p class="formInputs">
    <label for="lastName">Registration Number:</label>
    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" />
  </p>

  <p class="formInputs">
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" />
  </p>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

https://jsfiddle.net/5791od4x/
How do I get Your Policy number begins with.... to appear on to the right of the input area instead of below it?

flex box maybe. give display flex to the first forminput div
